# SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED has no effect on Server: 13.0.4206.0

Tags: sql-server, isolation-level

We just migrated from SQL Server 2008 (v10.x) to 2016 (v13.x), and when we ran some report queries that required a lot of time to complete, as a standard we would precede the query with:

```
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
    ...and then end it with:
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
```

This would allow users to continue performing their normal work without a PAUSE-SPIN, while the query ran.

However; since migrating, users may continue to work with OR without the isolation level set, ***BUT*** they experience notable sluggishness and pauses between screens; *again*, this is with OR without the isolation level set.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Which implies that you have made an invalid assumption about the cause of your problem. You will need to investigate more thoroughly - start by not making assumptions. Most likely you have issues with the actual queries not generating good execution plans.